Windows Server 2019 is no longer activated after switching over to passive node
I am running Windows Server 2019 in Virtual Machine Manager on a Synology High Availability cluster. Today I switched the server to the passive node and now Windows Server 2019 is no longer activated.
I tried to reactivated with the correct license key, but it says the key cannot be used:

The strange thing is the hardware is identical, but obviously the MAC addresses are different on the NICs.
Does anyone know what my options are at this point?
Thank you.

How is it licensed? Be aware that you should license every host it could run on in HA scenarios. You would need 8-core license per CPU (minimum) and 16-core pack per server (minimum).

@vidarlo I purchased 16-cores x 2.

@vidarlo unfortunately not, that link is not relevant to my situation.

As it turns out, you can run through their automated activation process by calling the registration center. They will send you a link to your mobile phone and you enter the 6 to 7 digit codes from A to H and you will get code you can enter on the next screen to activate Windows Server again. I ran through it and it took just 10 minutes and it worked perfectly.
I unfortunately forgot to snag a screenshot of the process, but you can get access to it under Activation settings once your Windows Server reports it is no longer activated.
